# Problema ao carregar imagem do banco com JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, cdi

Estou com um problema ao carregar imagens do banco com JSF e CDI, segue abaixo o código para uma melhor compreensão do problema.

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Detalhes Anuncio</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">

  <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">


                <h3> <i class="fa fa-building fa-1x"></i> Detalhes Anuncios </h3>

                <h:form>
                    <p:dataTable id="anunciosCad" var="anuncio" value="#{anuncioMB.listAnuncios}" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom" styleClass="table table-hover">

                        <p:column headerText="Anuncio Imagem" style="text-align: center;">
                            <p:graphicImage height="100" width="160" value="#{imagemMB.anuncioImagem}" styleClass="#{anuncio.id}" binding="#{imagemMB.graphicImage}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{anuncio.id}" width="60" style="text-align: center;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{anuncio.id}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Nome">
                            <h:outputText value="#{anuncio.nome}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Valor">
                            <h:outputText value="#{anuncio.valor}"> 
                                <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Descrição">
                            <h:outputText value="#{anuncio.descricao}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column width="60" style="text-align: center;">
                             <p:commandButton update=":form:anuncioDetail" oncomplete="PF('anuncioDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{anuncio}" target="#{anuncioMB.anuncioSelected}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

                </h:form>

                <h:form id="form">

                    <p:dialog header="Atualizar Anuncio" widgetVar="anuncioDialog" modal="true">
                        <p:outputPanel id="anuncioDetail">

                            <p:messages showDetail="true" closable="true"/>
                            <p:separator/>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                                <p:inputText styleClass="form-control" placeholder="informe o nome..." required="true" id="nome" value="#{anuncioMB.anuncioSelected.nome}"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="valor">Valor:</label>
                                <p:inputText styleClass="form-control" placeholder="informe o valor..." required="true" id="valor" size="12" value="#{anuncioMB.anuncioSelected.valor}">
                                    <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="descricao">Descrição:</label> 
                                <h:outputLink value="#" id="infoDescricao"> <p:spacer width="10"/> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></h:outputLink>
                                <p:tooltip value="Por favor informe uma descrição para o anuncio..." for="infoDescricao"/>

                                <p:inputTextarea id="descricao" required="true" styleClass="form-control" value="#{anuncioMB.anuncioSelected.descricao}"/>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h:commandButton value="Atualizar Anuncio" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" action="#{anuncioMB.atualizarAnuncio}"/>
                            </div>  

                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog> 

                </h:form>



            </div>
        </div>

  </div>

</ui:define>
```

E o meu ManagedBen está da seguinte forma:

```
package br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImage;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ImagemMB implements Serializable{



/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2583851912673523505L;



@Inject
private AnuncioMB anuncioMB;

private GraphicImage graphicImage;

public GraphicImage getGraphicImage() {
    return graphicImage;
}
public void setGraphicImage(GraphicImage graphicImage) {
    this.graphicImage = graphicImage;
}


public StreamedContent getAnuncioImagem(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }

    int id = 8;
    return new DefaultStreamedContent( new ByteArrayInputStream( anuncioMB.getMapAnuncios().get(id).getImagem() ) );
}

}
```

Detalhe: o ManagedBean que carrega a listagem de anuncios está como @Named e @ViewScoped utilizo o ImagemMB somente para carregar dynamicamente as imagens.

Dessa forma:

```
package br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import br.com.comparison.shoop.entity.Anuncio;
import br.com.comparison.shoop.service.AnuncioService;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AnuncioMB implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8900844371010166277L;


private Anuncio anuncio;
private Anuncio anuncioSelected;
private UploadedFile file;
private List<Anuncio> anuncios;
private Map<Integer, Anuncio> mapAnuncios;


@Inject
private UsuarioMB usuarioMB;

@Inject
private AnuncioService anuncioService;

public Anuncio getAnuncio() {
    return anuncio;
}

public void setAnuncio(Anuncio anuncio) {
    this.anuncio = anuncio;
}
public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public List<Anuncio> getAnuncios() {
    return anuncios;
}

public void setAnuncios(List<Anuncio> anuncios) {
    this.anuncios = anuncios;
}

public Anuncio getAnuncioSelected() {
    return anuncioSelected;
}

public void setAnuncioSelected(Anuncio anuncioSelected) {
    this.anuncioSelected = anuncioSelected;
}

public Map<Integer, Anuncio> getMapAnuncios() {
    return mapAnuncios;
}





@PostConstruct
public void init(){

    if (anuncio == null) {
        anuncio = new Anuncio();
    }

    if (anuncioSelected == null) {
        anuncioSelected = new Anuncio();
    }

}


public String salvarAnuncio() throws IOException{

    anuncio.setImagem(IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputstream()));
    anuncio.setEmpresa(usuarioMB.getUserSession().getEmpresa());
    anuncio.setDataCadastro( new Date() );

    anuncioService.salvar(anuncio);

    return "detalhes-anuncio";
}

public String atualizarAnuncio(){

    if (anuncioSelected == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nao localizou este anuncio");
    }

    anuncioService.update(anuncioSelected);

    return "detalhes-anuncio";
}


public List<Anuncio> getListAnuncios(){

    if (anuncios == null) {
        anuncios = anuncioService.list();

        mapAnuncios = new HashMap<Integer, Anuncio>(0);

        for (Anuncio a : anuncios) {
            mapAnuncios.put(a.getId(), a);
        }

    }

    return anuncios;
}


/*  public StreamedContent getImagen(){
    return new DefaultStreamedContent( new ByteArrayInputStream( mapAnuncios.get(8).getImagem() ),"image/jpg" );
}*/


}
```

Quando chamo a página pra listar os anuncios acontece o seguinte erro:

> Apr 28, 2015 6:18:38 PM org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler handle
>   SEVERE: Error in streaming dynamic resource. Error reading 'anuncioImagem' on type br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans.ImagemMB
>   Apr 28, 2015 6:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/comparison-shopp] threw exception
>   java.io.IOException: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'anuncioImagem' on type br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans.ImagemMB
>       at org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:78)
>       at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:72)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at br.com.comparison.shoop.filtros.AutorizacaoFilter.doFilter(AutorizacaoFilter.java:37)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'anuncioImagem' on type br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans.ImagemMB
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:91)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.*getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>       at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>       at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>       at org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:53)
>       ... 21 more
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
>       at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:691)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:79)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
>       at br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans.AnuncioMB$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.getMapAnuncios(Unknown Source)
>       at br.com.comparison.shoop.managedBeans.ImagemMB.getAnuncioImagem(ImagemMB.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
>       ... 27 more

Gostaria de entender onde estou errando.
Sei que esse processo não funciona para o @ViewScoped, por isso criei um managedBean somente para carregar a imagem do banco.

Comment: Esse link pode ser de seu interesse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/display-database-blob-images-in-pgraphicimage-inside-uirepeat

Comment: Não entendi o seu uso do "binding" no componente "graphicImage". Para que você precisa disso? Experimentou removendo o "binding" e deixando só o "value"? A uso do value parece correto.